# Disable click until page fully loads

Tags: javascript, wordpress, javascript-objects

I'm trying to disable click on the button on the page before the page fully loads. I've tried the code below, which should active the click for a particular element when the page is loaded:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("div#wc-proceed-to-checkout").click(function () {
      launchAction();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Alternative solution - disable click for the whole page until the page fully loads.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the disabled attribute on button to disable it.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_disabled.asp
and once the page loads remove the attribute
using - `removeAttr('disabled') method`

Answer (score 0):

Your script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $("div#wc-proceed-to-checkout").disable(false);
         $("div#wc-proceed-to-checkout").click(function () 
             {
                    launchAction();
           });
         });
 </script>
```

The HTML element must have disable true, or you can

```
<script> document.getElementById("wc-proceed-to-checkout").disable = true;
</script>
```